# excel macro to find and copy a block from one workbook to matching value in another workbook starting in the same row (using offset and resize)

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I think I've almost got it what I'm trying to do is update a clients report file from my workbook for each shift. 
The report is set up with a column with a date/time format (every 2 hours) for each quarter (i.e. "05/05/16 14:00" "05/05/16 16:00" ect).
I have set up my workbook with formulas to report the data in the same format.

[report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhZTg.png)

So what I need it to do is

1. open the report file
2. select the data in e18 (cell I've highlighted with red box)
3. find the cell in the report file
4. copy the block data with the purple box
5. paste(values) to matching location based on found data

here is the code I have so far it's finding the data but pasting it in the first row instead of the matching row. 
I'm new to VBA so its most likely something simple I didn't understand.

```
Sub ONGOING()

Dim rFndCell As Range
Dim strData As String
Dim stFnd As String
Dim fCol As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REPORTING")
Set sh = Workbooks.Open("F:\report.xlsm").Worksheets("Production data")
stFnd = ws.Range("E18").Value

With sh
    Set rFndCell = .Range("A:IV").Find(stFnd, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not rFndCell Is Nothing Then
        fCol = rFndCell.Column
        ws.Range("G18:N24").Copy
        sh.Cells(6, fCol).Offset(, 2).Resize(7, 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else 'Can't find the item
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    End If
End With
```

End Sub

Thanks

Comment: You are awesome works brillantly

Comment: My comment worked for you?

Comment: yeah it works - awesome

Comment: Great! I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `IF` condition replace

```
sh.Cells(6, fCol).Offset(, 2).Resize(7, 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

to

```
sh.Cells(6, fCol).Offset(rFndCell.Row, 2).Resize(7, 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```